# Python: replacing outliers values with median values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a python data-frame in which there are some outlier values. I would like to replace them with the median values of the data, had those values not been there.

```
id         Age
10236    766105
11993       288
9337        205
38189        88
35555        82
39443        75
10762        74
33847        72
21194        70
39450        70
```

So, I want to replace all the values > 75 with the median value of the dataset of the remaining dataset, i.e., the median value of `70,70,72,74,75`.

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Replace with 0, all the values that are greater than 75
2. Replace the 0s with median value.

But somehow, the below code not working

```
df['age'].replace(df.age>75,0,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for, you can use loc to assign value . Then you can fill the nan

```
median = df.loc[df['Age']<75, 'Age'].median()
df.loc[df.Age > 75, 'Age'] = np.nan
df.fillna(median,inplace=True)
```

You can also use np.where in one line

```
df["Age"] = np.where(df["Age"] >75, median,df['Age'])
```

You can also use .mask i.e

```
df["Age"] = df["Age"].mask(df["Age"] >75, median)
```

Comment: change to `Age > 75`. +1

Comment: Glad to help @user4943236

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is not an efficient way to deal with outliers in data.

You can refer to this article
https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-remove-outliers-from-a-pandas-dataframe-in-python

By calculating z scores for a column or entire dataset you can replace outliers with dynamic and mathematical calculations.

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution I've tried lately: replace 75 with the median of the whole column and then follow a solution similar to what Bharath suggested:

```
median = float(df['Age'].median())
df["Age"] = np.where(df["Age"] > median, median, df['Age'])
```

Comment: But the median value which is used as a threshold will be influenced by all the values(including the outliers) in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you code is almost right , but their is a gap.
use:

```py
df['age']=df['age'].replace(df.age>75,0,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a code for replacing outliers with a median in an `np.array`:

```
def replace_outliers_with_median(err_arr):
    a = err_arr
    med = np.median(a)
    outlierConstant = 1.5
    upper_quartile = np.percentile(a, 80)
    lower_quartile = np.percentile(a, 20)
    IQR = (upper_quartile - lower_quartile) * outlierConstant
    quartileSet = (lower_quartile - IQR, upper_quartile + IQR)
    # Find the outliers with 80% interval and replace them with median value 
    output = np.where((a >= quartileSet[0]) & (a <= quartileSet[1]), a, med)

    return output
```

**Example:**

```
arr =np.array([ [-8.33717,-8.3755,-7.83968,-7.09376, -6.37511,
                 -5.81576,-11.46364,-5.30386,-5.20346,-5.35983,
                 -5.35344,-5.2447,-5.04924,-4.98142,-4.72909,
                  4.86889,-4.95571,-4.93626,-5.17441,-5.18517,
                 -5.30639,-5.36995,-8]])

df = replace_outliers_with_median(arr)
```

**output:**

```
array([[-8.33717, -8.3755 , -7.83968, -7.09376, -6.37511, -5.81576,
        -5.30639, -5.30386, -5.20346, -5.35983, -5.35344, -5.2447 ,
        -5.04924, -4.98142, -4.72909, -5.30639, -4.95571, -4.93626,
        -5.17441, -5.18517, -5.30639, -5.36995, -8.     ]])
```